# how can i resolve import dart:html problem in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

> Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
> lib/homescreen.dart:1
> import 'dart:html';

[image]

Comment: Can you include full snippet? I think you just need to remove this import from top.

Comment: `dart:html` is available only if you're using Dart for the web (i.e. running in a web browser).  Is that your target platform?

Answer (score 1):

- This error occurs when we try to run the project for Android or IOS
  and not for web.
- There might be imports of **dart:html** in some files of your project. Remove those imports from all the files and run the app again to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have tried to import `Platform` or some other thing from auto suggestion and you ended up importing `'dart:html'` header. kindly remove the header and if you want to use `Platform` then you can import `'dart:io'`.

Let me know the update.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The same error occurs when I try to import this line.

```
import 'package:dio/browser.dart';
```

after having removed this, it works fine again